# Term for continuation of movement

Tags: terminology

I'm building a small app where the user can pan around on a fictional map. I want to implement a feature that basically all image viewer / map applications have: When the player scrolls around and lifts the finger, the map or image continues to move a bit in the last direction until it stops. As if the image had a physical momentum. Problem is: I'm not a native english speaker and don't know the right term for this behavior, so I can't search for it.
I searched for drag and inertia, but both don't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

"scroll inertia" or "inertial scrolling" sounds about right - and is used by e.g. [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-inertia.html) and [Apple](https://support.apple.com/zh-sg/guide/mac-help/unac899/mac)

Other terms used for this are "scroll momentum" ("momentum scrolling") and "kinetic scrolling".

Comment: Side note - "kinetic scrolling" as defined [by Wikipedia editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrolling) is slightly more precise, but i found it used to mean different things, so...